# ruby amazon S3 adding a file to existing folder not working

Tags: ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have a folder in amazon S3 `/clips/4182/` and i want to add a file `test.mp4` to it.
It uploads the file but in a newly created folder with same name `/clips/4182/` as the existing one so i end up having 2 folders of the same name instead of 1 folder with all my files in it.

Before upload

- bucket_name

  - clips

    - 4182

      - test.flv
      - test.jpg
  - pdf
  - cvs

After upload

- bucket_name

  - clips

    - 4182

      - test.flv
      - test.jpg
    - 4182

      - test.mp4
  - pdf
  - cvs

why? how do i get

- bucket_name

  - clips

    - 4182

      - test.flv
      - test.jpg
      - test.mp4
  - pdf
  - cvs

Code

```
 b_n = 'test.mp4'    
 base_name = /clips/4182/      
 place = 'bucket_name' + base_name      

 AWS::S3::S3Object.store(b_n, base_name, place, :access => :public_read, :content_type => mime_type)   
 url = AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(b_n, place, :authenticated => false, :content_type => mime_type)
```

Comment: `AWS::S3::S3Object.store("#{base_name}#{b_n},open(b_n),'bucket_name')`

Comment: i got this error:`/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:107:in` `current_bucket: No bucket name can be inferred from your current connections address (bucket_name) (AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified)`. and it doesn't do it with all the folders....

Comment: hmm..strange if you are always going to store these in the same place AWS recommends creating a subclass of `S3Object` and adding the method `set_current_bucket_to`. i.e. `class Clips < AWS::S3::S3Object;  set_current_bucket_to 'bucket_name'; end` then call as `Clips.store("#{base_name}#{b_n},open(b_n))`